# How to add docker run param to docker compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am able to run my application with the following command:

`docker run --rm -p 4000:4000 myapp:latest python3.8 -m pipenv run flask run -h 0.0.0.0`

I am trying to write a docker-compose file so that I can bringup the app using

`docker-compose up`. This is not working. How do "add" the docker run params to the docker-compose file?

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `command` to specify this.

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - '4000: 4000'
        image: myapp:latest
        command: 'python3.8 -m pipenv run flask run -h 0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
          - .:/code
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CMD` in your Dockerfile to specify this.  Since you'll want to specify this every time you run a container based on the image, there's no reason to want to specify it manually when you run the image.

```sh
CMD python3.8 -m pipenv run flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Within the context of a Docker container, it's typical to install packages into the "system" Python: it's already isolated from the host Python by virtue of being in a Docker container, and the setup to use a virtual environment is a little bit tricky.  That gets rid of the need to run `pipenv run`.

```sh
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /code
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock .
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system
COPY . .
CMD flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Since the `/code` directory is already in your image, you can actually make your `docker-compose.yml` shorter by removing the unnecessary bind mount

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    # no volumes:
```